# Cómo enviar parámetros por POST con RESTRequest en Delphi

Tags: php, delphi-berlin

Deseo enviar las variables codigo y nombre por POST a un web service en php, tengo este código en Delphi 10.4:

```
RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
//RESTRequest1.Body.Add... aquí iría lo del pase de parámetros
RESTRequest1.Method:= rmPOST;
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

La idea es recibirlo en php de esta forma:

```
$codigo=isset($_POST['codigo']) ? $_POST['codigo'] : NULL;
$nombre=isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
```

y así poder utilizar esos datos enviados.

otra forma sería contruir primero un JSON para pasarlo, eso también lo hice así:

```
content:='{'+
                    '  "usuario": "'+usuario+'",'+
                    '  "pass": "'+pass+'"'+
                    '}';
    RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
    RESTRequest1.Body.Add(content, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
    RESTRequest1.Method:= rmPOST;
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

pero content es solo un conjunto de datos, no posee nombre esa variable así que en php no consigo la forma de obtenerla y usarla puede ser de las dos formas, la primera me parece más práctica pero cualquiera de las dos me sirve. Estoy usando Delphi RAD studio community edition 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de enviar datos (o parámetros) en la petición, dependiendo de cómo deban llegar al Webservice en php.

Una forma sencilla es enviarlos como parámetros en la propia cabecera de la petición, utilizando el compoente `TRESTClient` que debes tener. Sería un código similar al que tienes a continuación:

```
RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
RESTClient1.AddParameter('Usuario', var_usuario, pkHTTPHEADER);
RESTClient1.AddParameter('pass', var_pass, pkHTTPHEADER);
RESTRequest1.Method:= rmPOST;
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

Otra opción es utilizar el body para enviar la información, tal y como tú comentas, utilizando un JSON con la información. En ese caso puedes utilizar la propiedad `Body` del componente `TRESTRequest`.
Puedes probar un código similar a este:

```
RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
RESTRequest1.Body.Add(sContent, TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
RESTRequest1.Method:= rmPOST;
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

Donde `sContent` es el `JSON` (como el que has utilizado tú en la pregunta).

Para recuperar esta última información en php (enviada en el body) puedes probar algo como esto:

```
$datosbody = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Neftalí, me sirvió la segunda opción, con la primera probé pero siguen sin enviarse las variables. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Seguramente sí se deben enviar en la cabecera, lo que habría que saber es cómo se capturan.